# Tomcat Maven Plugin Including Test Dependencies when it shouldn't

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have an maven module for integration tests, I am using the tomcat7-maven-plugin to spin up a few webapps and then have tests run against them.

Within my pom dependencies I have DependencyA that contains bean definitions needed for the tests to run.

When tomcat spins up in order to run the war files I get this spring error: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:

```
No qualifying bean of type [blah] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2
```

The 2nd bean that should not be found is within DependencyA (found due to component scanning), if I omit dependencyA the war files get deployed correctly (though I cannot run tests because they depend upon dependencyA). I have tried use

```
<useTestClasspath>false</useTestClasspath>
and
<useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
```

but neither seems to work

I'm at a loss for why the war files are finding DependencyA. I cannot modify anything except this integration pom due to versioning issues between all of the wars/jars.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `<exclusions>` for the DependencyA

Comment: I can't add exclusions because the test classes need what I would exclude